# delete_message() got multiple values for argument 'chat_id'

Tags: python, python-3.x

когда пишу в группе просто команду !ban бот отвечает мне и ошибок никаких нету, после того когда пытаюсь протестить данную команду на участнике беседы выдает данную ошибку
пытался исправить эту ошибку способом замены местами аргументы но не помогло потому что я так исправлял в этой же строке кода другую ошибку

````
import logging

from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types

from filters import IsAdminFilters

# log level
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

# bot init
bot = Bot(token=confing.TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

# active filters
dp.filters_factory.bind(IsAdminFilters)


# ban command
# noinspection PyArgumentList
@dp.message_handler(js_admin=True, commands=['ban'], commands_prefix="!/")
async def cmd_ban(message: types.Message):
    if not message.reply_to_message:
        await message.reply('эта команда должна быть ответом на сообщение!')
        return

    await message.bot.delete_message(message.message_id, chat_id=confing.GROUP_ID)
    await message.bot.kick_chat_member(chat_id=confing.GROUP_ID, user_id=message.reply_to_message.from_user.id)

    await message.reply_to_message.reply("Пользователь забанен!\nПравосудие совершилось")


# remove new user joined messages
@dp.message_handler(content_types=['new_chat_members'])
async def on_user_joined(message: types.Message):
    await message.delete()


# echo
@dp.message_handler()
async def filter_messages(message: types.Message):
    if 'плохое слово' in message.text:
        await message.delete()

# run long-polling
if __name__ == "__main__":
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)```
````

Answer (score 0):

```
await message.bot.delete_message(chat_id=message.chat.id,message_id=message.reply_to_message.message_id)
await message.bot.kick_chat_member(chat_id=message.chat.id, user_id=message.reply_to_message.from_user.id)
await message.reply("Пользователь забанен!\nПравосудие совершилось")
```

- Замените, Вы неверно передавали аргументы для  deleteMessage(),  нужно:chat_id, message_id.
- вместо await message.reply_to_message.reply() нужно использовать message.reply()

Comment: я сделал все в точности как ты мне сказал и он просто сообщение удаляет а участник остается. и потом так же ошибку показывает
aiogram.utils.exceptions.ChatNotFound: Chat not found

Comment: Можно полный код ошибки?

Comment: Попробуй код без всего лишнего: https://gist.github.com/batman22827/bc0930260e12a107c6952d52b25d6dd9

Comment: я попробывал не получилось, вообщем решил полностью переписать код по другому, спасибо за советы

Comment: Можно увидеть переписанный по другому код?